# Extract the century of a date from a string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

My task is to output the current century of a given date. The date can be represented as a `string`; for example, `19.03.2022`.

How can I retrieve the year and century of such strings?

Comment: You read the year as an int, you subtract one, or not, depending whether you consider 2000 to be 20th or 21st century. Then you divide by a hundred (with integer division) and add 1.

Comment: The century from the year is easy.  Getting the year from the string is complicated.  How many date formats do you need to support?  The simple `(myString.match(/\b\d{4}\b/) || [])[0]` will support a lot of them.

Comment: Explaining that code snippet, I'm using a regular expression to match a word boundary `\b` followed by 4 digits `\d{4}` followed by a word boundary.   If there is a match, you the 4 digits.  If not, the `|| []` gives you an empty array that will then give you `undefined` when you take its first entry.

Comment: @Jeffrey Then you delete your answer-in-a-comment and put it in the right place where it can be peer reviewed by the rest of us

Comment: @asteroidswithwings yeah. I'm lazy. I just wanted to point OP in the right direction without putting the needed effort. Is an answer-in-a-comment *that* bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string date = "19.03.2022";
int century = (date[6] - '0') * 10 + (date[7] - '0');
if(date[8] != '0' || date[9] != '0') century++;
cout<<century<<endl;
```

Output: `21`

Complexity: O(1)

Comment: Well done for getting the turn-of-century edge case right.

Answer (score 2):

The year of the given `string` is always contained within the last four characters, so you can use `string::substr` and then `std::stoi` to retrieve the year:

```
string str = "19.03.2022";
int year = stoi(str.substr(6, 4)); // year = "2022"
```

After that, you can use `year` to calculate the century:

```
int century = year/100 + 1; // century = 21
```

Comment: In the example given, the year was in the last 4 characters.  But in ANSII format it will be the first 4 characters.

Comment: @btilly OP didn't say anything about "ANSII format".

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings No, the OP just gave 1 example of a date.  The OP did NOT say whether that was the only format.

Comment: @btilly They gave an input, and a required output. Nothing about lots of different possible formats. You're making up a different question that is not this question.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings The question as asked is, "I want to find which century is from given string."  From the string given as an example, "It is in the 21st century" is a valid answer.  Would you consider that a good answer to the question as asked?  Of course not!  Why not?  Because you know that other strings will have to be dealt with.  The answer here will work for only one exact format, and has no error checking.

Comment: Yes, from _the given string_. Not from some other, completely different string that @btilly made up without being asked to. I'm not going to argue with you about this any more. When different input formats are required, you can switch to a proper date library.

Comment: behold the year of our Japanese emperor of year 2.  Or 999.

Comment: N.B. this is actually wrong; see Daniel's answer (though sadly he hasn't explained his code)